# How to change seekbar progress by 1000 from 10k to 20L?

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I would like to change the progress value by 1000 for each increment from min 10000 and max 2L value for the seekbar.

Here is the java code for the seekbar:

```
seekbar.incrementProgressBy(1000);
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser)
  {
    spinnervalue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);        
    spinnervalue.setText("$"+""+(progress+10000));
  }
});
```

Here seekbar incrementing by progress value and minimum value 10k is setting dynamically.

And here is the layout for seekbar used

```
  <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="1990000"/>
```

Please help by any suggestions basically it is incrementing 11880 i.e., (21880-10000) here 10000 is min value for the seekbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="200"/>


seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser)
  {
    spinnervalue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);        
    spinnervalue.setText("$"+""+(progress*1000));
  }
});
```

if you dont need zero then modify as follows

```
 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="190"/>

int mProgress =10000;
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser)
  {

    mProgress = progress*1000+10000;
    spinnervalue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);        
    spinnervalue.setText("$"+""+mProgress);
  }
});
```

and use mProgress every where else in program.

Comment: I hope you understood my logic here

Comment: Thanks for this , yes @Charan Pai i applied the same logic right now but i want it to display every progress by 1000 upto 20 lakhs and in layout i used 1990 as max value but for every progress it is incrementing by 4000 but i want only 1000 to increment..!

Comment: i think then you hav to devide it by 4, I didnt get your problem completely, have you tried above solution exactly same ?

Comment: and i think the 2nd solution is what u r lookin for exactly ?

Comment: yeah same code i applied  ofcourse if we divide it by 4 the progress value it does not append the value while incrementing the progress @Charan Pai

Comment: im looking the seekbar value to increment by 1000 from 10000 to 20 lakhs ie, 10000,11000,12000,...200,000,000. Hope u understand @Charan Pai

Comment: use spinnervalue.setText("$"+""+((progress*1000)+10000)); added one more braces there, what values you getting now ?

Comment: yeah i tried @Charan Pai but not getting and it is incrementing like 10000,17000,24000,like this im weird about this to get the values 1000 by every increment.

Comment: _xml code..._   `<SeekBar
 android:id="@+id/seekbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:max="1990"/> `    **java code**   
        `seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(MainActivity.this);`          **In the progress method**                                    `public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
    {  edit1.setText("$"+(progress*1000+10000)+"\n"); }`  @Charan Pai

Comment: change android:max="1990" to  android:max="190" and try.. let me know if you hav problem still

Comment: if we change to limit 400 also no problem occurs the problem occurs only when changing beyond 400 and above. And one more i want the seekbar value Range to Be **10k to 20laks** thats the issue here. @Charan Pai

Comment: y do you want to change it to 400 and all, let it be 190, and scale the progress as you need as in answer thats it.

Comment: i don hav acces to fb here in office.

Comment: upto that if we give **android:max="190"** it works fine but according to my problem it has to be 1990 @Charan Pai