# how to achieve IncrementprogressBy(0.5) in android

Tags: android, seekbar

My seekbar range is 0-10 , i want to increase the progress by 0.5 for each click on the progress bar. I have browsed and could not find a way.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/14950415/1619597

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make it 0-20 and increment it by 1

Comment: Why wouldn't this work? You'd have to handle the conversion between your range and the ProgressBar range internally, and basically "fake" the increment by 0.5 by dividing the actual progress by 2.

Comment: This is the approach that I took. You just show the correct value-increment in a label or text taking into account the progressbar internally goes from 0-20

Comment: okay so when i do something like this:  seekBar.incrementProgressBy(1);             
progressChanged = progress; int val = progressChanged/2;
measure.setText(""+val); --- its a editText  , i'm getting error "java.lang.stackoverflow" in setText line. and if i initialize myseekBar.incrementProgressBy(1), then my seekbar does not seek.

Comment: do you have an infinite loop or recursive method without base case? because the exception you got, points to that, can you provide more logcat output ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the function API does not support float arguments. Kindly use integers and adjust the range accordingly.